# JSON format issue in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, json

Following is my JavaScript code to get JSON data:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
          {
               $.support.cors = true;
               $.getJSON('http://example.com/root_dir/test_json.php', function(data1)
               {
                         alert("data1= "+data1); 
               });
          });
```

but the above alert shows me JSON in following format-

[image]

If I hit my php script URL in browser, it shows JSON data in expected formate as shown below-

```
[{"name":"AB","std":"7","number":"82"},{"name":"CD","std":"9","number":"90"},{"name":"PQ","std":"12","number":"79"}]
```

Following is my **test_json.php** code-

```
<?php

//Create an array
$json_response = array();

        $row_array['name'] = 'AB';
        $row_array['std'] = '7';
        $row_array['number'] = '82';

         array_push($json_response,$row_array);

        $row_array['name'] = 'CD';
        $row_array['std'] ='9';
        $row_array['number'] = '90';

         array_push($json_response,$row_array);

        $row_array['name'] = 'PQ';
        $row_array['std'] = '12';
        $row_array['number'] = '79';

        //push the values in the array
        array_push($json_response,$row_array);


   echo json_encode($json_response); 
?>
```

Comment: so wats the problem..Its correct.try with JSON.stringify(data1)

Comment: Why do you have `$.support.cors = true;`? You should never touch `$.support` it is there to tell jQuery if a browser supports a feature. You can't use it to turn cors support on in browsers that don't support cors.

Comment: @Quentin If I remove $.support.cors = true; it gives me "No Transport” error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getJSON` decodes the JSON into a JavaScript data structure.

Concatenating it with a string will implicitly call `toString()` on it. That will turn arrays in to a comma-seperated format and plain objects into `"[Object object]"`.

Nothing is going wrong. That is the expected behaviour.

If you want to see the data in JSON format, then use `JSON.stringify(data)` or use `.ajax` instead of `.getJSON` and access the raw text data in the `jqXHR` object.

Comment: Thanks..! I did it using "jqXHR object".